# Excel: Sum of Total Population per Continent (using Excel formulas - without Pivot)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, excel-2016

I was playing a bit with the data of nowadays topic: **Covid-19** and I downloaded some data to do some Analytics from:

https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide.xlsx

And this is what I managed to do using Power Query and Pivot tables:

[image]

From this data here - it is just a small piece of huge dataset:

[image]

Pivot tables are great and you can do a lot of things as you can see, BUT, what I wanted to do is do **calculations (sum per Continent with excel formulas** for the Total Population per Continent. There in the data set is lot of countries with certain Population and I am not managing the right way using `=max/if/sumif`. I just wanna know this way for myself!

I am sure that ain't that hard but I am now bit out of logic =)

I hope you got the point!!

**First Edit:**

**=sumif** doesn't work at the first place, because you have repetitive Population per one Country per day...it is summing the same land with its population per day - not what I need but only 1x the general sum of population.

Comment: `=SUMIF(E:E;"Asia";Column with the stat you want to sum)` for example (since E:E is the column holding the continent) you could use a `SUMIFS` if you need to filter by month, day or whatever...

Comment: Right..I know that already...but can you see by Column J that population is repetitive for every day for one country...that should not be like that but like filtered per one country on the certain continent.  Using what you suggested, gives me nonsense of numbers.

Comment: Well then if the population never changes, just pick one date and do the SUMIFS by continent and date, that way you will only get the population per country once. If it were to change, I'd use the function `MAX` when refereing to the date so you always get the newest date.

Comment: @Damian  Ah yeah, that was easy and logically! Will do the job =)) Thx man haha!